# In what ways does The Moviegoer echo Kierkagaardian existentialist principles?

Tags: inspiration, soren-kierkegaard, the-moviegoer, walker-percy

How does the plot of *The Moviegoer* show the influence of existentialist authors, specifically Kierkegaard, on Percy's writing. I've also noticed some similarities between the "leap of faith" between Kierkegaard and Walker, but it's too abstract for me to put into words.